# jQuery mobile and mvc4, how to redirect to a custom error page replacing "Error Loading Page" message

Tags: jquery-mobile, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to set up a custom error page (Error.vbhtml in Views/Shared folder) when an unhandled exception occurs. All I see is the "Error Loading Page" message on a yellow background.

These are what I've done so far to achieve the result:

1. I've set the customErrors mode ="On" in web.config
2. Checked that filters.Add(New HandleErrorAttribute()) is there in FilterConfig.vb
3. Threw an exception and using firebug's Net tab for the page where the error occurs, can see that the HTML tab has the custom messages in Error.vbhtml.

I am assuming that since jQuery mobile depends on ajax for page navigation, the error page is not getting displayed for some reason. How to display that page? Any ideas anyone?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved this by adding the following javascript code to _Layout.vbhtml within

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).live("pagechangefailed", function (e, data) {
            //alert("pagechangefailed live");
            var url = '@Url.Action("CustomError", "Account")';
            window.location.href = url;  

          }); 
        </script>
```

where CustomError is the newly created action in AccountController.